# Additional empty elements when splitting a string with re.split

Tags: python, regex, python-2.6

I'm trying to split a string looking like this in Python using re.split:

```
#NAME="Foo" NAME2="foobar" NAME3="BAR BAR"
comp = "NAME=\"Foo\" NAME2=\"FOO BAR\" NAME3=\"BAR BAR\""
```

This is how my split-function including regex looks like:

```
re.split('(\s\w+\=\".*?\")', comp)
```

The result looks like this:

```
['NAME="Foo"', 'NAME2="foobar"', '', 'NAME3="BAR BAR"', '']
```

While this is correct I'd like to get rid of all empty elements.

Comment: `=` does not need to be escaped, and neither do the quotes in the regexp.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your result in Python 2.7. Instead, the result is:  `['NAME="Foo"', ' NAME2="FOO BAR"', '', ' NAME3="BAR BAR"', '']`. Note the extra space before `NAME2`, no leading empty value.

Comment: I see a similar result to Martijn python 2.7.1

Comment: The empty values are the things between the splits. Split on the whitespace instead with look-ahead assertions, or use `findall()` instead.

Comment: the string I'm testing it with on my PC has a leading space. That's why I had a leading empty value. Fixed that in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
In [10]: re.findall(r'\w+=".*?"', comp)
Out[10]: ['NAME="Foo"', 'NAME2="FOO BAR"', 'NAME3="BAR BAR"']
```

?

It doesn't sound like `re.split()` is the right tool for the job.

Comment: I'd say so; splitting is handling the problem from the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a list comprehension and filter it directly

```
l = [x for x in re.split('(\s\w+\=\".*?\")', comp) if x != '']
```

The result looks like what you expect:

```
print l
['NAME="Foo"', ' NAME2="FOO BAR"', ' NAME3="BAR BAR"']
```

Comment: Does this resulted in o(n) time complexity?

Comment: You can replace `if x != ''` with `if x`